# KIF GOOGLE DRIVE AND UIRemoteView

Tags: ios, testing, automation, kif

I have an app which is using google drive, and I'm using KIF to perform UIAutomationTesting .

My problem is I'm not able to access the text field and buttons of the web view of the google drive log in page.

I've tried to use this solution: https://gist.github.com/seansu4you87/1904424

But not able to have access to a web view cause the view controller is of type UIRemoteViewController ....

Does anyone knows how to get access to the web view from this type of view controller ?

Thanks +!!!